# pandas assert_frame_equal behavior

Tags: python, pandas, testing

I am attempting to compare two DataFrames with pandas testing `assert_frame_equal`. These frames contain floats that I want to compare to some user defined precision.

The `check_less_precise` argument from `assert_frame_equal` seems to suggest that I can specify the number of digits after the decimal point to compare. To quote the API Reference page -

> `check_less_precise`: Specify comparison precision. Only used when check_exact is False. 5 digits (False) or 3 digits (True) after decimal points are compared. If int, then specify the digits to compare

[API Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

However, This doesn't seem to work when the floats are less than 1.

This raises an AssertionError

```
import pandas as pd

expected = pd.DataFrame([{"col": 0.1}])
output = pd.DataFrame([{"col": 0.12}])
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, output, check_less_precise=1)
```

while this does not

```
expected = pd.DataFrame([{"col": 1.1}])
output = pd.DataFrame([{"col": 1.12}])
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, output, check_less_precise=1)
```

can someone help explain this behavior, is this a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`check_less_precise` works more like relative tolerance. See details below.

I dug through the source code and found out what is happening. Eventually the function `decimal_almost_equal` gets called which looks like this in normal Python (its in Cython).

```
def decimal_almost_equal(desired, actual, decimal):
    return abs(desired - actual) < (0.5 * 10.0 ** -decimal)
```

See [the source code here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/testing.pyx#L37) Here is actual call to the function:

```
decimal_almost_equal(1, fb / fa, decimal)
```

Where in this example

```
fa = .1
fb = .12
decimal = 1
```

So the function call becomes

```
decimal_almost_equal(1, 1.2, 1)
```

Which `decimal_almost_equal` evaluates as

```
abs(1 - 1.2) < .5  * 10 ** -1
```

Or

```
.2 < .05
```

Which is `False`.

So the comparison is based on percentage difference and not total difference it seems.

If you want an absolute comparison, check out `np.allclose`.

```
np.allclose(expected, output, atol=.1)
True
```

Comment: So your not going to have much luck comparing anything to fa = 0.0

Comment: I think it takes a different path for 0. There is much more to the story than this little snippet.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I started to thinking that I'm blind or something, trying to figure out why I'm getting assertion errors although they shouldn't appear...

Comment: I was confused by `decimal_almost_equal`, which seemed like an absolute tolerance, but upon closer inspection, the call `decimal_almost_equal(1, fb / fa, decimal)` is really relative tolerance! Just want to make this note here in case others may be confused as well.